# Redux-thunk functions are not being returned when action is part of a redux-form

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-form, redux-thunk

I recently added redux-forms to my React/Redux/Redux-thunk project, and now if I submit information to a redux-thunk action, the info is submitted successfully, but nothing after the return function fires.

Everything was working as intended before adding redux-forms, so I think thatś the source of the problem, but even after double checking the docs for Redux, redux-form, and redux-thunk, I can't find any obvious errors in my connections or setup. What am I missing?

My reducer:

```
import {combineReducers} from 'redux';
import {reducer as formReducer} from 'redux-form';

import signUpReducer from './containers/SignUp/reducer';

export default function createReducer() {
  return combineReducers({
    signUpReducer,
    form: formReducer
  });
}
```

My form component:

```
import React from 'react';
import {Field, reduxForm} from 'redux-form';
import {validate, onHandleInfoSubmit} from '../../containers/SignUp/actions';

import {inputField} from '../../components/SmallUIBits/FormFields';

let UserSignUpForm = props => {
  const {handleSubmit} = props;

  return (
    <form className="NewAccountForm" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <div className="text-center">
        <small className="center-align">All fields are required</small>
      </div>
      <div className="AccountLine form-group">
        <Field classes="LoginInput form-control form-control-sm"
          component={inputField}
          label="Email address"
          name="email"
          placeholder="Enter email"
          required="true"
          type="text"
          value={props.email} />
      </div>
      <div className="form-row">
        <div className="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-xs-12">
          <Field aria-describedby="passwordHelp"
            classes="LoginInput form-control form-control-sm"
            component={inputField}
            label="Password"
            name="password"
            placeholder="Password"
            required="true"
            type="password"
            value={props.password} />
        <div className="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-xs-12">
          <Field classes="LoginInput form-control form-control-sm"
            component={inputField}
            label="Confirm password"
            name="passwordConfirm"
            placeholder="Re-enter your password"
            required="true"
            type="password"
            value={props.passwordConfirm} />
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  );
};

export default UserSignUpForm = reduxForm({
  form: 'UserSignUpForm',
  validate,
  onSubmit: onHandleInfoSubmit
})(UserSignUpForm);
```

My form container

```
import React from 'react';

import UserSignUpForm from '../../components/UserSignUpForm';
import SignUpSubmitBtn from '../../components/SmallUIBits/SignUpSubmitBtn';

class SignUp extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="Middle col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <UserSignUpForm />
        <SignUpSubmitBtn />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default SignUp;
```

My redux-thunk action:

```
export const onHandleInfoSubmit = values => {
  // trim data
  const userInfo = Object.keys(values).reduce((previous, current) => {
    previous[current] = values[current].trim();
    return previous;
  }, {});

  const {
    email,
    password,
  } = userInfo;

  console.log(userInfo);
  console.log('creating with email and password:');
  console.log(email);
  console.log(password);
  //^^ Works fine. No problems submitting info.

  //vv Does nothing. Return never returns.
  return dispatch => {
    // Auth imported from database.js
    console.log('Creating new account);
    auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .then(() => {
        const {currentUser} = auth;
        const userRef = database.ref(`users/${currentUser.uid}/data`);

        userRef.set({
          uid: currentUser.uid,
          email: currentUser.email,
          emailVerified: currentUser.emailVerified,
        });

        console.log('Account created successfully');
      },
      err => {
        const errorCode = err.code;
        const errorMessage = err.message;

        if (errorCode || errorMessage) {
          dispatch(newUserAccountCreateError(errorMessage));
          console.log(errorCode + errorMessage);
        }
      });
  };
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally figured this out.

As it turns out, I didn't need to return a function or use `dispatch` to trigger any of the actions I wanted to fire after successful form submit.

So my thunk action should in fact look like this.

```
export const onHandleInfoSubmit = values => {
  // trim data
  const userInfo = Object.keys(values).reduce((previous, current) => {
    previous[current] = values[current].trim();
    return previous;
  }, {});

  const {
    email,
    password,
  } = userInfo;

  console.log(userInfo);
  console.log('creating with email and password:');
  console.log(email);
  console.log(password);
  //^^ No change needed

  //vv remove the return function and all instances of dispatch()
    // Auth imported from database.js
    console.log('Creating new account);
    auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .then(() => {
        const {currentUser} = auth;
        const userRef = database.ref(`users/${currentUser.uid}/data`);

        userRef.set({
          uid: currentUser.uid,
          email: currentUser.email,
          emailVerified: currentUser.emailVerified,
        });

        console.log('Account created successfully');
      },
      err => {
        const errorCode = err.code;
        const errorMessage = err.message;

        if (errorCode || errorMessage) {
          newUserAccountCreateError(errorMessage);
          console.log(errorCode + errorMessage);
        }
      });
};
```

I still don't know if this is the solution because I'm using redux-forms in general or because I'm using [the remote submit](https://redux-form.com/7.1.,2/examples/remotesubmit/) feature of redux-forms (and I'm not changing my code to find out), but I hope this helps anyone else having the same problem.